# Import album-mysql Database received an error on my phpmyadmin from Lynda tutorial

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm following the MYSQL Essential Training on Lynda .when trying to Upload the Exercise Files on SQL for the "album-mysql"; I received an error on my phpmyadmin. I have following the instructions by selecting the UTF-8 from the character set of file.Error is showing below

```
 SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'album'  AND `table_name` = 'album'  AND FIND_IN_SET('INSERT',tracking) > 0
MySQL said: Documentation

#1100 - Table 'pma_tracking' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this from the `config.inc.php file`. I make sure that the Users i Logged in i Should used the same username and password

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```